# Multiplying individual elements of a list

Tags: netlogo

I have a list in Netlogo.

```
  let your-vec list xcor ycor
```

I wish to multiple the first element by a and second element by b.

I can achieve muilpltipcation of both using map.

```
set new-vec map [ ? * a ] new-vec
```

But am unaware of each individual multiplication methodology in NetLogo.

FOR EXAMPLE:

vec- [x1    x2]

muliptication vector [a     b]

result desired- [a * x1    b * x2]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can achieved with:
"replace-item"

```
show replace-item 2 [2 7 4 5] 15
=> [2 7 15 5]
```

Comment: I think you may have been trying to answer a different question. This doesn't seem relevant. If that's the case, you can delete this answer.

Comment: If I don't use show in front of replace-item does it works ?
In general in a big program how do we replace an item in a list. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Totally misinterpreted your question, sorry!

You're on the right track with `map`. `map` can take multiple lists as arguments and call multi-parameter reporters, so you can do:

```
(map * vec1 vec2)
```

or the expanded version:

```
(map [?1 * ?2] vec1 vec2)
```

Keeping the below should others find it useful:

Check out [`reduce`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reduce). `reduce` combines the elements of a list together using the given reporter. So for multiplication:

```
reduce * [ 1 2 3 4 ]
```

`reduce` will do `1 * 2` and then the result of that `* 3` and then the result of that `* 4`. So you get `(((1 * 2) * 3) * 4)`. In your case, you'd use it like `reduce * your-vec`.

That said, since your just working with two-dimensional vectors, you can just do

```
first your-vec * last your-vec
```

as well.

Comment: Please check the above example which makes it more clear. I am not sure if your code in it's correspondence.